# How can I decide the tab order within my Visual Studio code snippet?

Tags: visual-studio

From googling I understand that in VS Code you can use $1, $2, $3.... to decide the tab order.

Does anything like that exist in Visual Studio?

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: @mlst Hmm.. This was a while ago. I'm pretty sure I came to the conclusion that no, it's not possible. But I wouldn't bet my life on it. I switched jobs and forgot to bring my snippets along. :(